# SPD Workflow failed on start (retrying) - content approval

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I have a document library with checkin/Check out and Content approval enabled.

I have written SPD 2013 workflow against it. So that designated users will receive and email when document is uploaded with direct link to approve the content. I am running the workflow on document Add and change/edit.

Now user has requested that they should receive this approval email only on document add. not on edit/change.

So i did modifications in workflow accordingly. However, this is failing whenever there are edits to the document. With error

“Failed on start retrying”

“The workflow could not update the item, possibly because one or more columns for the item require a different type of information.”

I have to run on both item add and change, because document need to be auto approved in case of item edit. so it will become available to other users.

Where is the issue in this workflow?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced this kind of issue while creating an approval workflow. There is a strange behavior I found in logs.

After adding a `Log to History` list action, Set an action of `Pause`. This will resolve the issue, just try to add pause of 1 min after each `Log to history` list action.